# Changing the base URI in Adobe Analytics PhoneGap Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, adobe-analytics

How exactly can we parse the ADBMobileConfig.json in the implementation of the ADBMobile_Phonegap Plugin with the Andoid Mobile App Client. Also , how and where can i change the base URI , for which i have to track the events and send it to the server for further ANalytics.
Kindly provide any walkthrough example for the same to execute and test the same.

Do we need to generate the ADBMobileConfig.json specific to every Mobile App.

ADBMobileConfig.json -->

```
{
 "lastModified": "2014-12-09T17:17:09.626Z",
 "marketingCloud": {
  "org": ""
 },
  "target": {
   "clientCode": "",
  "timeout": 5
  },
 "audienceManager": {
  "server": ""
  },
 "acquisition": {
 "server": "c00.adobe.com",
 "appid": "bc281517fa3b45e7e602c54dea8b25e7448ec012d9bd76aab12cf328ff5c671c"
  },
 "analytics": {
  "rsids": "jhfsjhrpsmobileappdev.",
  "server": "CompanyName.sc.omtrdc.net",
  "ssl": false,
  "offlineEnabled": true,
 "charset": "UTF-8",
 "lifecycleTimeout": 300,
 "privacyDefault": "optedin",
 "batchLimit": 0,
 "timezone": "EST",
 "timezoneOffset": -300,
 "referrerTimeout": 0,
 "poi": []
} ,
 "messages": [],
  "remotes": {
   "analytics.poi": "https://assets.adobedtm.com/b213090c5204bf94318f4ef0539a38b487d10368/scripts/satellite-54acbcc165653600186f0300.json",
   "messages": "https://assets.adobedtm.com/b213090c5204bf94318f4ef0539a38b487d10368/scripts/satellite-54acbcc13936300015060b00.json"
 }
}
```

Index file -->

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <title>PhoneGap</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="ADB_Helper.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load',function(){
    alert('Document Loaded');

    });
document.addEventListener("deviceReady", function(){alert("Here call the ADB");}, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        alert('in On Device Ready method');
        // Note: A request for permission is REQUIRED by google. You probably want to do this just once, though, and remember the answer for subsequent runs.
    //  navigator.notification.confirm('GA_PLUGIN would like your permission to collect usage data. No personal or user identifiable data will be collected.', permissionCallback, 'Attention', 'Allow,Deny');
        } 

    function TrackButtonClicked()
    {
    alert('Track Button Entry');
//  ADB.trackState("login page", {"user":"john","remember":"true"});
 ADB.trackLocation('40.431596', '-111.893713');
    alert('Track Button Exit');
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body  id="stage" class="theme"> <!--  onload="onDeviceReady();" onunload="goingAway();" -->

  <h1>Test Adobe Analytics Plugin</h1>
  <div class="space"></div>
  <div>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="TrackButtonClicked();">Track Event</a>
    <!--<a style="height:200px; width:600px" onclick = "window.ADB.trackState('login page', {'user':'john','remember':'true'});">sampleHit</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="VariableButtonClicked();">Track Event with Variable</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="PageButtonClicked();">Track Page</a>-->
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Apart form these Using ADBMobile_PhoneGap.java and ADBHelper.js and adobeMobileLibrary.jar

Comment: @sanfor By any chance if you are aware of the same.

Comment: to change the base url, you change the `analytics.server` value. and yes, ideally you should register each app individually and each one will have its own id and config file

Comment: But i think there's some issue in parsing the ADBConfig.json file , cause i am getting the error .. Unable to read the ADBConfig.json @Crayon Violent

Comment: Well, it sounds like you either aren't pointing to the right path/to/file or else the file itself may be corrupt.  IOW that's not an Adobe-specific error..

Comment: can you tell me where to provide the path for ADBConfig.json file in the project , cause i pplaced it in assets/www but regarding its configuration with the project i am not sure.